# How should we understand "very handsomely so" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Sirius stared around at the students milling over the grass, looking
>   rather haughty and bored, but **very handsomely so**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I feel "**very handsomely so**" here means ***in a very handsome way***.  But I don't know if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in that case it is the usual meaning of *handsome* and the usual meaning of forming an adverb from an adjective with that suffix.

Just be careful in future, as *handsomely* is often used about a *different* sense of *handsome*, as in "I will reward you **handsomely**". It's still "in a handsome manner", but the meaning of *handsome* is different.